# Why does connecting a single resistor across 5V not decrease the voltage?

Tags: resistors

When I connect a multi meter across BC and AC I get the same reading, both show 5V, but isn't the resistor supposed to decrease the current/voltage?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fghH8S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Only if there is a current through it does it drop voltage.

Comment: there is current through it, multi meter make it a full connection.

Comment: That current is very small. Not enough for you to notice a difference. Try making R1 a thousand times larger. Or ten thousand times larger.

Comment: Try a 10Meg resistor and you'll see some voltage drop.

Comment: The resistor in the diagram is not across the 5V source as indicated in the title. It is in series with the source.

Comment: Even if it were in parallel, if the supply is capable pf producing enough current, the difference may not be significant enough to be discernable.  If you want to reduce voltage, try a voltage divider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many multimeter manufacturers have standardized their equivalent input resistance at ten MEGohms. Some precision voltmeters have much higher input resistance. But let's assume your multimeter looks like a 10M resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6xBPQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have a voltage divider, which means that \$V_m < 5V\$. But not much less. \$V_m\$ is what the multimeter will display.
You might use a 10V or 20V scale to display the 5V result: a 2V scale would over-range:

- A 3.5 digit multimeter would display 4.99, or 5.00
- a 4.5 digit multimeter would display 4.999 or 5.000

Since \$V_m = 4.9995\$ volts, the display resolution is too coarse to resolve the difference between 5.00000 and 4.9995

If your multimeter had better resolution, you should be able to see the drop.

Comment: Ok but I still don't get why the the voltage doesn't drop significantly until I add something else to the circuit like and LED? when I add an LED voltage drop to around 2 V. V = IR, in my circuit 5 = I * 1000, then I is 0.0005 amps which means there is barely anything going through the resistor itself? how is this possible.

Comment: Oh  is it because the multi meter has such a strong internal resistor that barely any current goes through it?

Comment: @Dan yes. The resistance around the loop is 10,001,000 ohms and the current is just under half a microamp.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Collins dictionary verifies that **megohm** is one million ohms, so 10 megohms is ten million ohms. But I note that peak usage occurred in 1948, falling since then. Have I sorta dated myself? Some folks here get **M** confused with **m**, so I thought that MEG makes a better distinction.

Comment: @glen_geek The SI brochure is very clear that M is Mega for 1'000'000 and m is milli for 0.001 . I didn't find any occurence of MEG, Meg, MEGohm, Megohm, MEGohms nor Megohms in there. If you want to be clear, just use 10 MΩ, 10e6 Ω, 10'000'000 Ω, 1e6 ohm or 10'000'000 ohm. And why the s at the end? There is no second in this unit.

Comment: (Ok there is second in the definition, 1 Ω = 1 kg * m^2 / ( s^3 * A^2 ). But no reason to multiply Ω * s here.) 10 Megaohm would also be clear.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 your question is not asked in good faith.

Comment: @hobbs MEGohms is just wrong, that is my point. Why do we spend billions to have exact units and a well defined norm when people refuse to use it. Is it so hard to follow the SI rules? They are short and they make sense.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 it's not "just wrong", you're just ignorant of English usage and too busy being sanctimonious to learn better. There are no SI prefixes here. Your rulebook is irrelevant. "megohm" is standard usage. Capitalization is emphasis.

Comment: @hobbs Megohm is wrong, period, Megohms is even more wrong. Read the SI Brochure. And yes, Capitalization is important. But i guess for some people 3 Mm and 3 mm is the same, despite the factor 1'000'000'000 between them.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I accept your knowledge of the SI brochure, but questions and answers on this site are written in the English language, which contains many words that are not found in the brochure. As soon as you see one of those words, you should take that as your cue that people are speaking in a foreign language in which you are illiterate, and that you have nothing to offer by "correcting" their usage in a language which they have mastered considerably better than you have.

Answer (score 4):

The voltage dropped across the resistor is proportional to the current flowing through it; the constant of proportionality is the resistor's value: V = I*R. When the resistor does not have current through it, as when it is open circuited or connected to a multimeter which has an impedance orders of magnitude higher than 5k ohms, there will be no measurable voltage drop across it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see the picture as a liquid pipe with a reducer (resistor). As long as the reducer is blanked the pressure (voltage) will be the same before and after it. If you leave the liquid flow (current) pass then the outlet pressure will be less than the inlet.

Comment: Maybe full of water but plugged?